# Add space to an xml value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have an xml value like this as an input file:

`<digit1>1234</digit>
<digit2>5678</digit2>`

I want the digits to be formatted and processed like:

`<digit1>1234    </digit>
<digit2>    5678</digit2>`

How can I add the spaces for each field value? Digit1 and Digit2 has fixed length which is 8. If the value is ony 4, add spaces to it. Digit1 is leftalign and digit2 is right align.

I have something like this but not working

`<xsl:variable name="RightPadding" select="'        '"/>
<xsl:variable name="LeftPadding" select="'        '"/>`

```
<!-- Function to left-pad (right justify) -->
<xsl:function name="PadLeft">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:variable name="leftPad">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($LeftPadding,1,$length - string-length(string($string)))"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($leftPad, $string)"/>
</xsl:function>

<!-- Function to right-pad (left justify) -->
<xsl:function name="PadRight">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($string,$RightPadding),1,$length)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

`<xsl:value-of select="PadRight(digit1,8)"/></Invoice_No>
<xsl:value-of select="PadLeft(digit2,8)"/></Gross_Amount>`

many thanks

Comment: There is http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_pad-string-to-length.html, for instance. If you have written code for `PadRight` or `PadLeft` and it doesn't achieve what you want, then show us minimal but complete samples together with an exact error description or the desired and current result. We can't fix a function `PadRight` where you don't show the code.

Comment: Please make clear which version of XSLT is needed. Tagging with all three versions isn't helpful.

Comment: @MichaelKay xslt2 or 3 thankyou:)

Comment: @MartinHonnen here's the missing piece:   
    <xsl:function name="PadLeft">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="length"/>
        <xsl:variable name="leftPad">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($LeftPadding,1,$length - string-length(string($string)))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($leftPad, $string)"/>
    </xsl:function>

Comment: @MartinHonnen   <xsl:function name="PadRight">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="length"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($string,$RightPadding),1,$length)"/>
    </xsl:function>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue about the code you posted seems to be that you haven't put your functions in a namespace, that is required for user-defined functions; with some clean up to use type declarations (`as="sequence-type"`) and to use `xsl:sequence` to return strings and not text nodes your code becomes

```
  <xsl:param name="RightPadding" select="'        '"/>
  <xsl:param name="LeftPadding" select="'        '"/>

  <!-- Function to left-pad (right justify) -->
  <xsl:function name="mf:PadLeft" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:variable name="leftPad" 
      select="substring($LeftPadding,1,$length - string-length($string))"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="concat($leftPad, $string)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <!-- Function to right-pad (left justify) -->
  <xsl:function name="mf:PadRight" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="substring(concat($string,$RightPadding),1,$length)"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

That way at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1xW it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="leftPadding">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('        ', $value), string-length($value)+1)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="rightPadding">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($value, '        '), 1,8)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="valueWithLeftPadding">
  <xsl:call-template name="leftPadding">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="/root/digit1"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="valueWithRightPadding">
  <xsl:call-template name="rightPadding">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="/root/digit2"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<result>
<digit1><xsl:value-of select="$valueWithLeftPadding"/></digit1>
<digit2><xsl:value-of select="$valueWithRightPadding"/></digit2>
</result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<root>
<digit1>abcdef</digit1>
<digit2>abcdef</digit2>
</root>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><result>
<digit1>  abcdef</digit1>
<digit2>abcdef  </digit2>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to pad to width 8 on the right is

```
substring(concat(X, '                '), 1, 8)
```

and on the left:

```
substring(concat('              ', X), 8 - string-length(X))
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect in its 2nd part - see demo here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AcskP/1

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single function with the ability to select the direction of the alignment (as well as the fixed length and the padding character) as a parameter:

```
<xsl:function name="my:pad-to-fixed-length">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:param name="char"/>
    <xsl:param name="alignment"/>
    <xsl:variable name="padding" select="for $i in (1 to $length) return $char"/> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$alignment='left'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(string-join(($string, $padding)), 1, $length)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$alignment='right'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(string-join(($padding, $string)), string-length($string) + 1)"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AcskP